# LocalStorage is unstable with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, local-storage

I've got a PhoneGap app which uses localStorage to store created data when the user is offline - when a connection is restored, the data is synced with the REST API via Backbone.js.

This mostly works fine, except for some issues where the app the quits, or it crashes.

For example:

1. User logs into app as **User A** (app calls `localStorage.setItem('api_key', key)`)
2. User logs out of app (app calls `localStorage.removeItem('api_key')`)
3. User logs into app as **User B**
4. User logs out of app
5. User closes app, then quits it from memory
6. User opens app, and they're logged in as **User A**.

Using a remote debugger, we've found that events which cause the app to be completely quit (eg. a crash or a manual quit) seem to interfere with localStorage - some data would be old or missing.

Is LocalStorage not stable enough for an app to use?

This occurs only with iOS, over many versions of PhoneGap - we've tried at least 2.2 to 2.9.

Comment: There were some issues with localStorage persistence around 2.5 or so, but it's certainly fixed in 2.8+ AFAIK.